# Android blogger in my app

Tags: android, blogger

How are you,

How I can do my blogger in my app ?

I have layout only for my blogger  to read anything in my blogger from my app

So I need a tutorial for that.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you want to show your blog in an android application ?

Comment: Yes my friend can you help me

Comment: you know something about " WebView " in android

Comment: please go through the link .if any confusion, plz ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this tutorials for displaying blog in your android application.

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

Hope this will help you